# Why does my iOS app no longer run in the iOS 5.0 Simulator in Mountain Lion?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, osx-mountain-lion

I was forced to upgrade to Mountain Lion so that I could use Keynote.

Now my iOS app does not run under the simulator. I was using iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk earlier. Now when I run the app, it gives the error

> The simulated application quit. Click Relaunch to try again.

There is an option to switch SDK but there is only one SDK installed and nothing to switch to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Forced because of keynote... ? How did that happen? You needed iCloud?

Answer (score 3):

You should download and install the IOS 5.0 Simulator, to do so:

1. open Xcode
2. from Xcode menu select Preferences... (or press cmd+,)
3. go to the Downloads tab
4. under Components you'll find IOS 5.0 Simulator, install it.